# How to assign the internal methods as property types in am5Chart

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, amcharts5

I am using `am5Chart` for my plotting purpose. there I have an `any` type, which is failing with `eslint`. trying to fix but got no  result.

here is my code :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Inject, NgZone, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5';
import * as am5flow from '@amcharts/amcharts5/flow';
import am5themes_Animated from '@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated';
import * as am5xy from '@amcharts/amcharts5/xy';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'hf-workspace-graphsample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss'],
})
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private root: am5.Root = am5.Root.new('chartdiv1');
  root1: am5.Root = am5.Root.new('chartdiv1');

  series: any; //here is the issue what would be the correct proptype?
  data = [
    {
      date: '2013-01-16',
      market0: 71,
      market1: 75,
      sales0: 5,
      sales1: 9,
    },
    
    {
      date: '2013-01-30',
      market0: 81,
      market1: 85,
      sales0: 4,
      sales1: 7,
    },
  ];
  constructor(public router: Router, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any, private zone: NgZone) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.root1.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(this.root1)]);

    this.root1.dateFormatter.setAll({
      dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      dateFields: ['valueX'],
    });

    const chart = this.root1.container.children.push(
      am5xy.XYChart.new(this.root1, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: 'panX',
        wheelY: 'zoomX',
        layout: this.root1.verticalLayout,
      })
    );

    chart.events.on(
      'panended',
      function (ev: { type: 'panended'; target: am5xy.XYChart }): void {
        console.log('clicked on ', ev.target);
      },
      this
    );
    // Add cursor
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
    const cursor = chart.set(
      'cursor',
      am5xy.XYCursor.new(this.root1, {
        behavior: 'zoomX',
      })
    );
    cursor.lineY.set('visible', false);

    // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.DateAxis.new(this.root1, {
        baseInterval: { timeUnit: 'day', count: 1 },
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(this.root1, {}),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {}),
        tooltipDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      })
    );

    const yAxis0 = chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root1, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(this.root1, {}),
      })
    );

    const yRenderer1 = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(this.root1, {
      opposite: true,
    });
    yRenderer1.grid.template.set('forceHidden', true);

    const yAxis1 = chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root1, {
        renderer: yRenderer1,
        syncWithAxis: yAxis0,
      })
    );

    const columnSeries1 = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(this.root1, {
        name: 'Actual sales',
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis0,
        valueYField: 'sales1',
        valueXField: 'date',
        clustered: false,
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {
          pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
          labelText: '{name}: {valueY}',
        }),
      })
    );

    columnSeries1.columns.template.setAll({
      width: am5.percent(60),
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
    });

    columnSeries1.data.processor = am5.DataProcessor.new(this.root1, {
      dateFields: ['date'],
      dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    });

    const columnSeries0 = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(this.root1, {
        name: 'Target sales',
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis0,
        valueYField: 'sales0',
        valueXField: 'date',
        clustered: false,
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {
          pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
          labelText: '{name}: {valueY}',
        }),
      })
    );
    columnSeries0.columns.template.set('width', am5.percent(40));
    const series0 = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(this.root1, {
        name: 'Market days',
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis1,
        valueYField: 'market0',
        valueXField: 'date',
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {
          pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
          labelText: '{name}: {valueY}',
        }),
      })
    );

    series0.strokes.template.setAll({
      strokeWidth: 2,
    });

    const series1 = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(this.root1, {
        name: 'Market days all',
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis1,
        valueYField: 'market1',
        valueXField: 'date',
      })
    );

    series1.strokes.template.setAll({
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeDasharray: [2, 2],
    });

    const tooltip1 = series1.set(
      'tooltip',
      am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {
        pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
      })
    );
    tooltip1.label.set('text', '{name}: {valueY}');

    const scrollbar = chart.set(
      'scrollbarX',
      am5xy.XYChartScrollbar.new(this.root1, {
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        height: 60,
      })
    );

    const sbDateAxis = scrollbar.chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.DateAxis.new(this.root1, {
        baseInterval: {
          timeUnit: 'day',
          count: 1,
        },
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(this.root1, {}),
      })
    );

    const sbValueAxis0 = scrollbar.chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root1, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(this.root1, {}),
      })
    );

    const sbValueAxis1 = scrollbar.chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root1, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(this.root1, {}),
      })
    );

    const sbSeries0 = scrollbar.chart.series.push(
      am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(this.root1, {
        valueYField: 'sales0',
        valueXField: 'date',
        xAxis: sbDateAxis,
        yAxis: sbValueAxis0,
      })
    );

    sbSeries0.columns.template.setAll({ fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeOpacity: 0 });

    const sbSeries1 = scrollbar.chart.series.push(
      am5xy.LineSeries.new(this.root1, {
        valueYField: 'market0',
        valueXField: 'date',
        xAxis: sbDateAxis,
        yAxis: sbValueAxis1,
      })
    );

    const legend = chart.children.push(
      am5.Legend.new(this.root1, {
        x: am5.p50,
        centerX: am5.p50,
      })
    );
    legend.data.setAll(chart.series.values);

    columnSeries1.data.setAll(this.data);
    columnSeries0.data.setAll(this.data);

    series0.data.setAll(this.data);
    series1.data.setAll(this.data);

    sbSeries0.data.setAll(this.data);
    sbSeries1.data.setAll(this.data);

    series0.appear(1000);
    series1.appear(1000);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
    series0.events.on(
      'click',
      function (ev: { type: 'click'; target: am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries }): void {
        console.log('clicked on  series0', ev.target);
      },
      this
    );
    columnSeries0.events.on(
      'click',
      function (ev: { type: 'click'; target: am5xy.ColumnSeries }): void {
        this?.router.navigateByUrl('/example');
        console.log('clicked on columnSeries0 ', ev.target);
      },
      this
    );

    this.root = am5.Root.new('chartdiv');
    this.root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(this.root)]);
    this.series = this.root.container.children.push(
      am5flow.Sankey.new(this.root, {
        sourceIdField: 'from',
        targetIdField: 'to',
        valueField: 'value',
        nodeWidth: 20,
      })
    );
    this.series.nodes.rectangles.template.setAll({
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
      strokeWidth: 1,
      cornerRadiusTL: 4,
      cornerRadiusTR: 4,
      cornerRadiusBL: 4,
      cornerRadiusBR: 4,
    });

    this.series.nodes.get('colors').set('step', 2);
    this.series.data.setAll([
      { from: 'A', to: 'B', value: 10 },
      { from: 'B', to: 'C', value: 8 },
      { from: 'C', to: 'D', value: 4 },
      { from: 'C', to: 'E', value: 3 },
      { from: 'D', to: 'G', value: 5 },
      { from: 'D', to: 'I', value: 2 },
      { from: 'D', to: 'H', value: 3 },
      { from: 'E', to: 'H', value: 6 },
      { from: 'G', to: 'J', value: 5 },
      { from: 'I', to: 'J', value: 1 },
      { from: 'H', to: 'J', value: 9 },
    ]);
    this.series.nodes.rectangles.template.setAll({
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
      strokeWidth: 1,
      cornerRadiusTL: 4,
      cornerRadiusTR: 4,
      cornerRadiusBL: 4,
      cornerRadiusBR: 4,
    });

    this.series.nodes.labels.template.setAll({
      x: am5.percent(50),
      centerX: am5.percent(50),
      textAlign: 'center',
    });
  }
  myFunction(ev: { type: 'click'; target: am5xy.ColumnSeries }) {
    console.log('clicked on ', ev.target);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what if you use type from `am5` import, like `series: am5.ColumnSeries[]`

Comment: @pankaj getting an error `Property 'series' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` so i tried as ` this.series = [];` in constructor. still error exist

Comment: @PankajParkar - another try : `series: am5.ColumnSeries[] = [];` error as : `has no exported member 'ColumnSeries'.ts(2694)`

Comment: Can you please check [this docs link](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/tag/interface/) , if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

The type should be am5flow.Sankey, because that is the element you are creating, also since you are not assigning the value directly, it can also be undefined. (series: am5flow.Sankey | undefined;)